# What would my return type be if I want to return the whole response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am working on testing some APIs with RestSharp and have a method which I would like to return the whole response object.

Here is my method I am just wondering what the return type would be. Kind of a noob to C# which is why I am asking.

```
    public static SendGetRequestWithResponse(string endpoint)
    {
        RestRequest request = new(endpoint, Method.Get);
        var response = _restClient.ExecuteGet(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Hover your mouse over `var` and it should tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a RestResponse object. Check [their official docs](https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#basic-usage) here for more details.